# Django bootstrap modal window

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have this kind of problem: I don't load my data in a django bootstrap (22.3.2) modal window .I want to load a text given its index. I don't know where si my error. Thi si my code

MAIN.HTML

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="show_modal_topic.html/{{topic_id}}/" data-target="#myModal">click me</a>
{% include "show_modal_topic.html" %}
```

URLS.PY

```
url(r'^show_modal_topic.html/(\d+)/$', views_topics.load_topic),
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def load_topic(request, topic_id):
    topic = tab_topics.objects.get(id_topic=topic_id)
    text_topic = topic.text
    return render_to_response("show_modal_topic.html", {
                                     'text_topic': text_topic,
                                                        },
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

SHOW_MODAL_TOPIC.HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Opinione</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {{text_topic}}

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me please? I can not understand where I'm wrong. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to update your urls.py to define variable name passed to the view as

```
url(r'^show_modal_topic.html/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views_topics.load_topic),
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan, I'll try this out, I appreciate you taking the time to help me out

Comment: I have a problem: the modal windows is laod in the all page and not like a modal window. Where is the problem?

Comment: @RoverDar, not sure may the content of page returned or ajax handling.